# inotifywait script case statement stops working after a while

Tags: bash, shell-script, inotify

I have the following bash script, run at system startup to view files dropped into the `/srv/mutt` directory.  It works perfectly for a while but then simply stops 'seeing' files arriving in `/srv/mutt`.

I added the echo statements to try and diagnose what's wrong.  This shows that the `inotifywait` sees the files and they're reported in `/tmp/waitAndView.log` but the viewing program doesn't get called.

What's going wrong?  Does anyone have any ideas on the cause or on how to diagnose the problem?  It seems''

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
# script to detect new files in /srv/mutt and display them, run from 'Session & Startup'
#
cd /srv/mutt                    # where the files appear
shopt -s nocasematch            # ignore case in case (erk!)
#
#
# inotifywait will output the name of any file that is rsynced into /srv/mutt
#
inotifywait -m -q -e moved_to --format %f /srv/mutt/ | \
#
#
# Handle file as appropriate
#

while read -r file; do
    echo $file >>/tmp/waitAndView.log
    case $file in
        dbapost*)
            #
            #
            # run dbapost on the received message file
            #
            /home/chris/.cfg/bin/dbapost $file &
            ;;

        *.pdf)
            #
            #
            # View PDF file with atril
            #
            atril $file &
            ;;

        *.jpg|*.png|*.jpeg)
            #
            #
            # View other image formats with nomacs
            #
            nomacs $file &
            ;;

        *.html)
            #
            #
            # HTML file is an E-Mail to view with web browser
            #
            $HOME/bin/browser --new-tab file:///srv/mutt/$file &
            ;;

        *)
            ;;
    esac
    echo finished with $file >>/tmp/waitAndView.log
done
```

Comment: Hoe the ***&&&""" do you get this stupid system to accept code?  I say 'code' and paste the script and it results in the above total rubbish!

Comment: Paste it as normal, select the code, then hit the code button.

Comment: Try giving the full path to `atril` and`nomacs` etc. On my system that would be `/usr/bin/atril`...

Comment: The one I caught after adding the diagnostics was an html file so the 'viewer' has a full path.  So, for example, I have in the log file:-

mutt-esprimo-1000-793619-13564711348920342824.html
finished with mutt-esprimo-1000-793619-13564711348920342824.html
'''

Comment: Re the 'code' formatting, or not, it appears OK to me now.  Has someone fixed it or was it just a display problem for me?

Comment: @ChrisGreen, yes, someone fixed it. See how it says "edited 22 hours ago" under the post, with don_crissti's username next to it. The post editor is a bit silly in that the toolbar button for code blocks uses the indentation syntax, which is hard to paste code in, even though the triple-backtick fences are also available. (Hit the question mark in the right side of the toolbox, then "advanced help", then the first "show more" link, under the "Code and Preformatted Text" section)

Answer (score 0):

One of the programs being run within the `case` statement is stealing the input. Consider this example:

```bash
seq 9 | 
while read f
do case $f in 
   4) cat -n & ;;
   *) echo got $f ;;
   esac
done
```

This can be the output:

```
got 1
got 2
got 3
     1  6
     2  7
     3  8
     4  9
got 5
```

Once the `cat` is started, it can read the pipe before the `while read` manages to.  You need to close off standard input, typically by adding `</dev/null` to the "browser" command and so on.

Comment: Aha, thank you, I'll try dding a </dev/null to each 'viewer'